# Vue 3 :is component with tab icons

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I have made a tab overview and in order to not overload the api with calls, I put them in a loop like described in the documentation: [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

It all works but my tabs have icons and translations and I am unsure how to implement them.

I tried changing the tabs object to an array with the icon and translation inside them, which works but then the < component :is = "tabs[currentTab]" doesnt work anymore, no errors, no console errors, just blank tab.

My question is, how can I use this Vue 3 functionality in script setup with icons and translations?

Here is component:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill nav-icons" id="tabsWithIcons" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"
                    v-for="(_, tab) in tabs"
                    :key="tab"
                    :class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
                    @click="currentTab = tab">
                    <button class="nav-link justify-content-center" :class="[{ active: currentTab === tab }]" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">
                        <BootstrapIcon icon="share-fill" />
                       <span>{{ tab }}</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content my-4" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">
                  <component :is="tabs[currentTab]"></component>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the code in my script:

```
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import Contact from '@/views/Contact.vue'
import AboutMe from '@/views/AboutMe.vue'


import { ref } from 'vue'

const currentTab = ref('Home')

const tabs = {
  Home,
  Contact,
  AboutMe
}
```

**I have tried**

Changing the tabs = { } to:

```
const tabs = [
  { name: 'Home', icon: 'house-fill', translation: i18n('message')} ,
  { name: 'Contact', icon: 'telephone-fill', translation: i18n('message')} ,
  { name: 'AboutMe', icon: 'person-fill', translation: i18n('message')} ,
]
```

And then the icons and tab labels work (when I change tab to tab.name in the template etc), but the tab content stays empty due to < component :is="tab[currentTab]"  not getting it... Also the translations are not working..

I also tried making a getCurrentTab function that loops through the tabs array and returns the tab name but then I get some weird void is not a string error...

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Heres the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/little-water-fyx9w8?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A22%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A2%2C%22startColumn%22%3A22%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A2%7D%5D

Comment: You either use `:is="tabs[currentTab.name]"` or you change `@click="currentTab = tab"` to `@click="currentTab = tab.name"`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75698320/2487565) in my other question.

Solution for the for the `<script setup>`

```
<script setup>
...
</script>
<script>
   export default {
      icon: 'home-icon',
      name: 'Home'
  }
</script>
```

---

Just put all the tab properties inside your components

```
<template>
  <div class="tab">
    Home component
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
      name: 'Home',
      icon: 'house-fill'
  }
</script>
```

And then

```
<button
   v-for="(tabObj, tab, index) in tabs" 
   :key="tab"
   :class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
   @click="currentTab = tab"
 >
  icon: {{tabObj.icon}}, name: {{ tabObj.name }}
</button>
```

Here is the updated [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort! My components also use script setup so when I copy the code and implement it, it doesn't work for me, as the syntax is different. I tried const icon = ref('send-fill') but nothing.. just a blank space..

Comment: Watch on my other question [How to access SFC data properties from the parent not using $refs in Vue v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698091/how-to-access-sfc-data-properties-from-the-parent-not-using-refs-in-vue-v3)

Comment: Thanks, so you also not sure how it's done in script setup? I will watch for answers on your question and hope someone knows..

Comment: I saw it, thanks.. it's not a very nice solution but it gets the job done. Now trying to figure out how to make the translations work in <script> ..

Comment: anyway `defineExpose` is only for those with expertise or experience or in a situation where it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

your idea of ​​`tabs` is `array` is correct you just need to add components to them and then refer them to `<component />`:

```
const tabs = [
  { name: 'Home', component: Home, icon: 'house-fill', translation: i18n('message')} ,
  { name: 'Contact', component: Contact, icon: 'telephone-fill', translation: i18n('message')} ,
  { name: 'AboutMe', component: AboutMe, icon: 'person-fill', translation: i18n('message')} ,
]
```

and

```js
<component :is="tabs[currentTab].component" />
```

> for `v-for` above also need modification like when you convert `tabs` to `array`

[Resolve your example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

> your minimal reproducible example is different from the code you provided i don't understand why you do but you will have to port your own as they are different

Comment: This is so much cleaner, except the translations are not working because they need to be computed. I don't know how to workaround this

Comment: use computed. `translation: computed(() => i18n('message'))`. i'm not sure the syntax `i18n()` is correct vig `vue-i18n` is `i18n.global.t()`

Comment: it's your problem and it's not in the scope of the question you have to fix it yourself or create a new question

Comment: The playground works and I didnt see it, thanks!