# How to access SFC data properties from the parent not using $refs in Vue v3?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup, vue-sfc

I have this Vue 3 SFC

```
<template>
  <div>
    Home component
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
      name: 'Home',
      icon: 'house-icon'
  }
</script>
```

And I can access it's `name` & `icon` properties from the parent.

```
import Home from './Home.vue'

icon: {{Home.icon}}
```

How to achieve the same `Vue.js` way, using `data()`, `setup()` or `<setup script>`?

I have already tried

```
<script>
  export default {
      data() {
         return {
             icon: 'home-icon'
         }  
      }
  }
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
  export default {
      setup() {
         const icon = 'home-icon'
         const icon2 = ref('home-icon')
         const icon3 = computed(() => 'home-icon')
         return {
             icon, icon2, icon3 
         }  
      }
  }
</script>
```

and

```
<script setup>
    const icon = 'home-icon'
    const icon2 = ref('home-icon')
    defineExpose({
      icon,
      icon2
    })
</script>
```

Every time my `Home` component does not have any icon data I could access.
No JS errors in the console.

Any ideas?

Here is the [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) to play around

Comment: How are you accessing the data in the parent?

Comment: [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) exposes the properties on the _component instance_, not the exported component (which is a constructor of sorts). So that definitely won't work.

Comment: The same argument applies to your first example and to regular `setup()`.

Comment: For the Options API or `setup()`, you can simply put them as properties in your default-exported object. For `<script setup>`, you can add a regular `<script>` block and default-export an object with them there.

Comment: This is assuming that you want them on the exported component, not the component instance.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes both solutions work. Thanks lot!

Comment: I'm gonna write up an answer anyway, just to properly put out what I said in the comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component data is available on the *component instance*, not the exported component itself (which is a constructor of sorts).
This applies to the Options API, to regular `setup()`, and to data in a `<script setup>` exposed via [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) (bindings created in `<script setup>` are not exposed by default; see the linked docs).

For the Options API or the Composition API with `setup()`, you can simply put them as properties in your default-exported object. For the Composition API with `<script setup>`, you can add a regular `<script>` block and default-export an object with them there.

**Options API / `setup()`:**

```html
<script>
export default {
  icon: 'home-icon',
  // data() or setup(), etc.
}
</script>
```

**`<script setup>`:**

```html
<script setup>
// ...
</script>

<script>
export default {
  icon: 'home-icon',
}
</script>
```